# Memory leak in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks

I am using **GTK**, and I am not sure with *malloc()* function here. Valgrind gives me a memory leak, what I am doing bad? 
at first I create pointer to pointer to pointer to GTK widget, because I need three dimensional array.

```
GtkWidget*** widgets;
```

and I am using malloc like this:

```
widgets = malloc((1)*sizeof(GtkWidget**));
    for(i = 0; i<= l-1; i++) // l = 4 in my case
    {
        widgets[i] = malloc((1)*sizeof(GtkWidget*));
        for(j = 0; j<=3; j++) // 4 is number of elements in this dimension
        {
            widgets[i][j] = malloc((1)*sizeof(GtkWidget));
        }
}
```

and at the end I am doing this:

```
widgets[0][0] = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("MyLabel");
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(indicator_menu), widgets[0][0]);
```

my array can be smaller and bigger, so I am using dynamic allocation of array, my maximal array indexes are something like widgets[3][3].
I did not post whole code, because it is pretty long, I sent here just the parts for which was valgrind complaining to. What I am doing bad? thank you.

Comment: you allocate `1 * sizeof`, but you use 4

Comment: yes, but it is inside for loop so it is allocated 4 times, at least I thought that it works this way

Comment: That's the next dimension you are allocating within the loop, but indexing the previously inadequate array.

Comment: As a little point of technique `i<=l-1;` would be cleaner as `i<l;`

Comment: @WeatherVane so if I understand it right, my last (j) loop should be deleted? (and yes, i<l looks more clear :) )

Comment: As @Wimmel wrote. `widgets[i] = malloc(4*sizeof(GtkWidget*));` because you go on to index by `j=0..3`

Comment: never ever use l as a local variable. It is hard to make distinction between l and 1. widgets = malloc((l)*sizeof(GtkWidget**)); is what you needed iso widgets = malloc((1)*sizeof(GtkWidget**));

Comment: In every case, `malloc(1* ...)` is allocating for a 3d array of order [1][1][1]. In the innermost one, the size should be the data size, not the pointer size, unless the array actually holds pointer values.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allocating the size of a pointer, when you mean to allocate an array of pointers.

```
// this will allocate a single character pointer
char ** ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));

// this will allocate n character pointers
char ** ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
```

So if you want a two dimensional array of dimension NxM, you'll need to allocate an array of size N, then walk through that array from 0 to N-1 and allocate arrays of size M.

What you're doing now is assigning pointers returned from malloc to memory you don't own. Is what you actually want a two-dimensional array of pointers to GtkWidget structures?

Answer (score 1):

Using l as a local variable is not a good idea. It is very easy to make a mistake between l and 1, in some editors they look very much the same.

```
widgets = malloc((l)*sizeof(GtkWidget**)); //is what you needed
```

iso

```
widgets = malloc((1)*sizeof(GtkWidget**));
```

Over here with syntax highlighting the problem immediately appears.
So another suggestion is to for sure use an editor with syntax highlighting